# how to pass multidimensional array in multithreading c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference

I was trying to create multithreading to handle 2 multi-dimensional arrays:

```
vector<thread> tt;  
for(int i=0;i<4;i++) tt.push_back(thread(th,arr1,arr2));
```

with the threaded function :

```
void th(int arr1[3][100][100], int arr2[100][100]) {
...
}
```

I also tried to pass by reference yet not get it work as well:

```
void th(int (&arr1)[3][100][100], int (&arr2)[100][100]) {
    ...
    }
```

Both of them gives me an `"no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of void(* (int **[])..."` error. Can someone please show me how to correctly pass multidimensional arrays in multithreading?

Comment: Take out the multithreading and focus on getting your function declarations and calls right.

Comment: `tt.push_back(thread(th, std::ref(arr1), std::ref(arr2)));` with [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) and `th` taking references to arrays (so `void th(int (&arr1)[3][100][100], int (&arr2)[100][100])`)

Comment: http://ideone.com/RkR40P See how easy it is with std::array. Never use raw arrays

Comment: @PiotrS. Thanks Piotr. I tried ref indeed, however, got the same error.

Comment: @ChuNan please attach the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original function call smells strange to me, but still the following call compiles and runs just fine with `g++-4.6.3` using the command

```
g++ -lpthread -std=c++0x -g multiArray.cc -o multiArray && ./multiArray
```

Then `multiArray.cc` has

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void th(int ar1[3][100][100], int ar2[100][100])
{
    std::cout << "This works so well!\n";
}

int main()
{
    int ar1[3][100][100];
    int ar2[100][100];

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(int ii = 0; ii<4; ++ii)
    {
        threads.emplace_back(th, ar1,ar2);
    }


    for(auto & t : threads)
    {
        if(t.joinable())
        {
            t.join();
        }
    }
}
```

Let me clarify that this code is suspect; for instance, if you change the array sizes (without changing your array dimensions) this code compiles without problem.

Comment: Thanks. Can we also pass by reference?

Comment: I assume it's faster if the array values are changed?

Comment: @NickThompson a pointer to array drops its first dimension, a reference doesn't